# avoid checking examples for R package building using devtools

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am using `devtools` to build my R package, and use the function `check` to check the package (with a long list of outputs on screen). However, because my package includes examples, and some of the examples are time-consuming, I am wondering how can I suppress checking examples when checking the package in `devtools`. The `check` function itself seems to not have such option. Thanks!

Comment: Gavin's solution is what you need but for future reference you can find the additional arguments you can pass to `check` from a command line by running `R CMD check --help`

Comment: @Dason - good point +1. I added this to my Answer whilst editing in information about how to pass more than one argument.

Comment: Why do you not want to run examples? The point of test is to be comprehensive, and the strategy of devtools is to provide functions that allow you to just do part of check (e.g. `check_docs()` and `run_examples()`). Also, if your examples take too long to run, CRAN will complain.

Comment: @hadley: actually I was doing a quick-and-dirty check of the package. It is not at the final stage, so I'll revise the example before submitting to CRAN. But anyway, thank you hadley for the suggetions ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the `args` argument appropriately with command line arguments to `R CMD check`. The latter has `--no-examples` so try

```
check(...., args = "--no-examples")
```

where `....` are the other arguments you were using for `check()`.

You can see all the arguments for `R CMD check` by running it with `R CMD check --help` at a command prompt/shell. To pass more than one to `check()` you'll need to concatenate them into a character vector, e.g.:

```
check(...., args = c("--no-examples", "--no-tests"))
```