# Execute only check of examples and test files with `R CMD check`

Tags: r, cran

As runnning a full `R CMD check` takes a while, I am curious if there is a shortcut to only execute checking of the examples' and test files. See the part of `R CMD check` output I am interested in below.

I am not looking for add-on packages that would require a change of my test files (like `testthat`) to perform something similar. Rather, I would like to have the same stuff executed as `R CMD check`, i.e., generate exampels R, check differences vs. reference output (.Rout.save) and the same for test files, and produce the *.Rout files.

This would aid in package development as it speeds up testing and update of reference outputs, esp. in case of small changes.

```
* checking examples ... OK
* checking differences from 'pkg-Ex.Rout' to 'pkg-Ex.Rout.save' ... OK
* checking tests ...
  Running 'test1.R'
  Comparing 'test1.Rout' to 'test1.Rout.save' ... OK
  [... further test files ...]
```

Comment: See [chapter 8](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Tools) of r internals. There you have a whole list of options you can turn off when running R CMD Check. Also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158049/avoid-checking-examples-for-r-package-building-using-devtools). Or outsource all of this by using github actions.

Comment: Thank you. I consulted R Internals prior to posing the question. I can seem to find options that allow the shortcut I am looking for... Do you have any specific ones in mind?

Comment: In the 'devtools' package there's a function to check the examples.

Comment: Here is what Writing R Extensions says in footnote 21: "The best way to generate such a file is to copy the .Rout from a successful run of R CMD check. If you want to generate it separately, do run R with options --vanilla --no-echo and with environment variable LANGUAGE=en set to get messages in English. Be careful not to use output with the option --timings (and note that --as-cran sets it)."

Answer (score 0):

As @Stéphane Laurent pointed out in their comment, there is [`devtools::run_examples(".")`](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/run_examples.html), which tests your examples in your package's docs  quite a bit quicker than R CMD check. From it's doc:

> One of the most frustrating parts of R CMD check is getting all of your examples to pass - whenever one fails you need to fix the problem and then restart the whole process. This function makes it a little easier by making it possible to run all examples from an R function.